# Awaiting the end of a process.nextTick loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, stack-overflow, event-loop

### Context

I am writing a nodejs application that involves some heavy calculations.  The underlying algorithm involves a lot of iteration and recursion.  A quick summary of my code might look like this:

```js
// routes.js - express.js routes

router.get('/api/calculate', (req, res) => {

  const calculator = new Calculator();
  calculator.heavyCalculation();
  console.log('About to send response');
  res.send(calculator.records);

});
```

```js
// Calculator.js

class Calculator {

  constructor() {
    this.records = [];
  }

  heavyCalculation() {
    console.log('About to perform a heavy calculation');
    const newRecord = this.anotherCalculationMethod();
    this.records.push(newRecord);

    if (records.length < max) {
      this.heavyCalculation();
    }
  };

  anotherCalculationMethod() {
    // more logic and deeper function calls 
    // to methods on this and other class instances
  };

};
```

In most cases I would expect the `max` value to never be more than 9,000 or 10,000, and in some cases, it may be far less.  As I said, this is a calculation heavy application, and I am trying to find the right approach to performing the calculations in a way that will not crash the machine the app is running on.

### First issue - `Maximum call stack size exceeded error`

Even though what you see above is not an infinite loop, it quickly hits the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error (for obvious reasons).

[Here is a codesandbox demonstrating that issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-stack-overflow-1-cbh5r?file=/src/Calculator.js:426-452). Click the button to make the api call which runs the function.  If `max` is low enough, we get the expected behavior - `heavyCalculation` runs recursively, populates Calculator.records, and then when the limit is hit, the full results gets sent back to the front end.  The logs look like this:

```
About to perform a heavy calculation
About to perform a heavy calculation
About to perform a heavy calculation
// repeats max times
About to send response
```

But if you set the `max` variable to be high enough, you'll exceed the stack limit, and the app crashes.

### Trying to solve the issue with `process.nextTick` or `setImmediate`

I read the article [The Call Stack is Not an Infinite Resource — How to Avoid a Stack Overflow in JavaScript](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-call-stack-is-not-an-infinite-resource-d530df0041bc), and opted to try some methods there.  I liked the idea of using `process.nextTick`, as it would help dicretize each step in the recursive loop of `heavyCalculation`.  Adjusting the method, I tried this:

```js
  heavyCalculation() {
    // ...

    if (records.length < max) {
      process.nexTick(() => {
        this.heavyCalculation();
      });
    }
  };
```

This solves the max call stack size exceeded issue, but creates another problem.  Rather than run `heavyCalculation` recursively, and then waiting until that recursion hits the limit, it runs the function once, then sends the response to the front end with `records` containing only a single entry, *then* continues the recursion.  The same occurs when wrapping the call in `setImmediate`, i.e. `setImmediate(this.heavyCalculation())`. The logs look like this:

```
About to perform a heavy calculation
About to send response
About to perform a heavy calculation
About to perform a heavy calculation
About to perform a heavy calculation
// repeats max - 1 times
```

### [Codesandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-stack-overflow-2-gic2q?file=/src/index.html)

As before, click the button to make the api call which fires the function, and you can see what's happening in the codesandbox nodejs terminal.

How can I properly manage the event loop such that my recursive function does not create a stack overflow, but fires in the proper order?  Can I leverage `process.nextTick`?  How can I separate the call stack for each iteration of the recursive function, but still wait for the end of the loop before returning the response?

#### Bonus question:

What I've posted is obviously a simplified version of my app.  In reality, `anotherCalculationMethod` is in and of itself a complicated function with its own deep call stack.  It iterates over a series of arrays, which may also grow to be quite large (on the order of thousands).  Say it iterates over `Calculator.records`, and `Calculator.records` grows to be several thousand items large.  Within a single iteration of `heavyCalculation`, how can I apply the same flow logic that might solve the main question to avoid the same issue happening within a subroutine like `anotherCalculationMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question regarding "how to wait for the next tick":
You can pass a callback-function to the calculation function and wrap it in a promise, which you then can await, e.g.:

```
heavyCalculation(cb) {
        console.log("About to perform a heavy calculation");
        const newRecord = this.anotherCalculationMethod();
        this.records.push(newRecord);

        if (this.records.length < max) {            
            process.nextTick(() => {
               this.heavyCalculation(done);
            });
        } else {
            cb(this.records);
        }
    }
```

In your request handler you can call it like this:

```
const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calculator.heavyCalculation((result) => {
        resolve(result);
    });
});
console.log("about to send calculator.records, which has length:", result);
res.json(result);
```

***But***:
You have to keep in mind that although the use of `process.nextTick` solves the stackoverflow problem, it comes with a price. I.e. you block the event-loop from moving on to the next phase and that means, for example, that node will not be able to serve other incoming requests to your server. Those requests and actually all other callbacks that are ready to be pushed to the call-stack **have** to wait until your calculation has finished.

You can e.g. use `setTimeout` as an alternative in order to solve this, but
if you have to rely on such heavy calculations, you might be better off with [worker-threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads) and moving those calculations there.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I knew I needed some kind of `else` block to fire the next section of the algorithm, I just wasn't sure how to organize it.  Wrapping the whole loop in a promise works nicely.  My code already involves a lot of async, so adding another async process in there would be fine.  As for the issue of blocking api calls, my program is growing in complexity to the point where I need to start thinking about larger-scale architecture, and how to manage it, whether that be with worker threads, event emitters, 2nd-layer servers, or some combo thereof.  Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is only dummy code, but from what I see, there is simply no reason for the recursion.  I am a big fan of recursion, even in JS.  But as you're seeing, it has real limitations in the language.

Also, recursion is closely tied to functional programming with its insistence on immutable data and lack of side-effects.  Here your recursive function is not returning anything -- a major warning sign.  And it's only job seems to be to call another method and use the result to add to `this.records`.

To me, a `while` loop makes much more sense here.

```js
heavyCalculation() {
  while (this.records.length < max) {
     console.log('About to perform a heavy calculation');
     const newRecord = this.anotherCalculationMethod();
     this.records.push(newRecord);
  }
};
```

### Update

A comment asked how to do this with `process.nextTick`.  As eol points out, the way to deal with that is to use Promises or the syntactic sugar of `async`/`await`.  Once you mix asynchronous processing in, all code it touches will also need to be asynchronous.  That's just the nature of the beast, and it was at least touched on in [the article mentioned](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-call-stack-is-not-an-infinite-resource-d530df0041bc).

And it looks as though your queue is controlled simply by a max size value, in which case, what eol suggested would work fine.

But there are other cases where the current iteration might add work to your queue, and you want to continue until there is no more work to do.  Think of spidering a website.  You want to follow all the relevant links, and all the links from those pages, and all the links from those, as deep as necessary, but to load each page only once, regardless of how many links there are to it.  That can use a fairly similar process, just managing a queue of those to visit and a set of those already visited.  Here's an example, with a dummy replacement for `fetch` and an extremely naive model where all links are followed.  (I also skip HTML scraping; let's not go there!)

```js
const spider = async (id) => {
  const queue = [id], 
        processed = []
  const items = {}
  while (queue .length > 0) {
    const id = queue .pop ()
    const item = await fetch (`http://dummy.url/item/${id}`)
    items [id] = item
    processed .push (id)
    item .links .forEach (id => processed .includes (id) || queue .push (id))
  }
  return items
}

spider (1)
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>/* Dummy version of `fetch` */ const fetch = ((data) => (url, t = url .slice (url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), item = data .find (({id}) => id == t)) => new Promise ((res, rej) => item ? res (item) :rej (`Item ${t} not found`)))([
  /* using this data */
  {id: 1, name: 'foo', links: [2, 3]}, 
  {id: 2, name: 'bar', links: [4]}, 
  {id: 3, name: 'baz', links: []}, 
  {id: 4, name: 'qux', links: [5]}, 
  {id: 5, name: 'corge', links: [6]}, 
  {id: 6, name: 'grault', links: [1, 2]}, 
  {id: 8, name: 'waldo', links: [3]}
])</script>
```

This fetches all the items that can be found recursively linked starting with `id` of `1`.  (If we started with `id` of `8`, we would only get `8` and `3`, but with `1` we get all our hard-coded data except for `8`.)

The important point to note is that the calls to `fetch` are asynchronous, and so `spider` itself is asynchronous, but we can work in a mostly synchronous manner internally, using `await`

Comment: That's a fair point.  While my code is a fair bit more complicated than the dummy code, it was fairly easy to refactor to use this pattern.  That did solve the issue.  It also unblock this step to allow me to discover that I have the same issue in many other places in my app - so I have a lot of work to do as far as writing iterative, calculation-heavy code in a nodejs app.  Your answer provides an alternative to using `process.nextTick` in a loop, but it doesn't really answer how to await the end of a loop using process.nexTick before executing the next step. But I appreciate your insight!

Comment: @SethLutske: added an update to show an additional technique.  It's probably not relevant to your exact case, but can show how to handle a more complex queue of work.

Comment: "Once you mix asynchronous processing in, all code it touches will also need to be asynchronous" - thank you for mentioning this.  This is something I've been thinking about *a lot*, as the real code in question is a large algorithm, with a deep call stack, some of which are async.  I will need to come up with a tactic for awaiting the async parts when needed, but allowing the sync parts to run unhindered, preferably without having to make *every* function in the stack `async`.  I've been formulating *that* question in my head for weeks, and will post it soon.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: @SethLutske Note that what I said could be taken too strongly.  If `A` calls `B`, `C`, and `D`. and `C` calls `E`, and if `E` is asynchronous, then `C` must also be asynchronous, and hence `A` must be so as well.  But `B` and `D` could still be synchronous.  Perhaps it would be better said, "Anything that calls asynchronous code, directly or indirectly must itself by asynchronous."

Comment: I think I understood what you mean, but its an interesting topic in javascript of how to organize a function stack within an algorithm when certain branches of logic are async, while others are not.  For example, if `A` calls `B` and `D`, and `B` and `D` are both synchronous, but run loops that may eventually trigger the asynchronous `C` to run, whats the best way to write that?  I'm going to post another question on that topic, as its a different subject, and I'll put a comment here so that you can take a look if you're interested.  It might be awhile though.  Thanks for your insight

Comment: Well this discussion inspired me to finally write that question.  If you're interested, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383006/managing-sync-and-async-functions-in-an-algorithm-call-stack